# Why does the console seem to still consider variable to have type: any when declared otherwise in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Im curious why, in typescript, code like this works?

```
let number = 35;

console.log(number);

let numbers: boolean = 35;

console.log(numbers + number);
```

and outputs 70?

Why doesn't console return undefined? Isn't part of the point of typescript the idea that you assign static types to variables?

Thanks

Comment: What console are you doing this in? Most consoles I'm aware of are **JavaScript** consoles, not **TypeScript** consoles. I'd expect syntax errors from the above.

Comment: `let numbers: boolean = 35;` TypeScript would choke on that for sure. `35` isn't a boolean.

Comment: What console are you using? Chrome: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: I'm using codepen

Answer (score 2):

> Isn't part of the point of typescript that you can assign static types to variables?

Yes.

Whatever console you're using seems highly unusual, in that it seems to accept TypeScript type annotations, but ignore them. Otherwise, this would obviously fail:

```
let numbers: boolean = 35;
```

since 35 isn't a boolean.

Type errors are caught by TypeScript at **compile**-time, when TypeScript compiles the TypeScript code to JavaScript code. But the compiler generally outputs the resulting JavaScript even if type errors occur, and of course, JavaScript is loosely typed, so it doesn't care. Meaning the code you're actually running is probably:

```
var number = 35;
console.log(number);
var numbers = 35;
console.log(numbers + number);
```

[Live copy in the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20number%20%3D%2035%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(number)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20numbers%3A%20boolean%20%3D%2035%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(numbers%20%2B%20number)%3B) -- you can click Run and it will show 35 and 70.

I think the take-away here is: If TypeScript shows you an error, don't run the resulting JavaScript code (or don't pay any attention to the result of running it if you do).

Comment: Yeah, maybe I should find a different console, because this doesn't even show any errors... weird.

Comment: @NOAH - I'm **very** surprised by that, but just dropped by codepen.io and set it to use TypeScript as the "preprocessor" and I sure don't see any errors anywhere, either. (I don't use CodePen, but I would have expected some indication of "preprocessing" errors *somewhere*.)

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right, typescript should throw an error, however it seems that while codepen claims to support typescript it doesn't actually have working error highlighting, I would suggest you try the official [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html).

However, usually the transpiler does output the javascript, even if there are errors, so always be careful and pay upmost attention to any typescript errors you may see.